# How do I add a line to a rich textbox?

Tags: c#, textbox, richtextbox

I have written the following code to create a simple dictionary application:

```
    private void btnDefine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string word = txtWords.Text;
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        try
        {
            string [] words = txtWords.Text.Split('\n');
            foreach (string word in words ){
            xDoc.Load("http://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v1/references/collegiate/xml/" + word + "?key=[KEY]");
            txtWords.Text = (xDoc.SelectSingleNode("entry_list/entry/def/dt").InnerText);

            Clipboard.SetText(txtWords.Text);
            lblCopied.Text = "Copied to the clipboard!";
        }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("That is not a word in the dictionary, please try again.", "Word not found in the dictionary", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        }

    }
}
```

}
This form contains a rich textbox of which you could enter words in and it will define the word for you. Now as soon as I enter a word in the textbox, I get the definition. but if I enter two or more words in the textbox, I get the definition of the last word on the list, how do I make it so that all of definitions show and in new lines. I.E., if I enter three words in the textbox and press btnDefine, I will get the defintions of all of the three words in the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could output the definitions similiarly to how they're input: on separate lines. See [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
List<string> definitions = new List<string>();
foreach (string word in words )
{
    xDoc.Load("http://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v1/references/collegiate/xml/" + word + "?key=[KEY]");
    string definition = (xDoc.SelectSingleNode("entry_list/entry/def/dt").InnerText);
    definitions.Add(definition);
}
txtWords.Text = String.Join("\n", definitions);
Clipboard.SetText(txtWords.Text);
lblCopied.Text = "Copied to the clipboard!";
```